# Segmentation fault error for `create_directories`

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, c++17

I compile the following code with gcc-9 in QtCreator in Ubuntu:

```
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    bool any_new_folders = create_directories("aaa");
    printf("success");
}
```

But a run-time error with message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` closes the program in line:

```
bool any_new_folders = create_directories("aaa");
```

however the folder `aaa` is created beside the exe file. The exe file is created in a folder inside home folder.

Why does it happen and how can I solve the problem?

---

Step by step executions shows that the problem happens in a function named `_M_split_cmpts` in `fs_path.h` (line 184). `fs_path.h` is a standard header file.

Comment: Suggest as a first step you put a `try/catch` around the call, the variant without the error code parameter may cause an exception.

Comment: try catch did not work... no exceptions caught

Comment: Then the next step I would take is to fire up `gdb` (or any other debugger) and find out exactly where it's crashing. One thing you *could* try is to use a static path (of path type) rather than the `const char *` Not sure how bug-free implementations are of this feature, the fact that it wants a `const ref` means it *may* be going out of scope before the destructor. But, since that's really just clutching at straws (I've never actually *used* it), my advice is to get `gdb` involved.

Comment: It really looks like `create_directories()` is not ready for prime time.  Not only does it crash on your system, but it isn't even implemented on MacOS until version 10.15 which was only released a few weeks ago.

Comment: @paxdiablo the same problem exists if I compile in terminal with `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`. I don't think gdb is involved here.

Comment: @nano, I perhaps didn't make myself clear enough, my wife says that's a fairly common thing for me :-) I wasn't placing the *blame* on `gdb`, merely stating that you'll probably have to debug your code *with* `gdb` to find out what's going on.

Comment: @paxdiablo‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌@paxdiablo :)

Comment: What c++ standard are you using?

Comment: @A.Smoliak g++ -std=c++17